# Wrong status callback event in Twilio Programmable Voice

Tags: nestjs, twilio

I am using Twilio Node.js SDK and Nest.js to develop my application. Currently facing an issue that Twilio programmable voice status callback is firing a wrong status. I need to handle an `answered` (`in-progress`) event but it is firing immediately after `ringing` event even if the call is not answered. I am receiving calls on third-party application, so I think this can caused by the third-party application called Hushed.

Twilio call initializer

```js
async init(to: string, from: string): Promise<string> {
    const call = await this.twilio.api.v2010.accounts(<ACCOUNT_SID>).calls.create({
      url: `${API_URL}/api/twilio/stream`,
      statusCallback: `${API_URL}/api/twilio/statusCallback`,
      statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
      statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
      to,
      from,
      method: 'POST',
      record: true,
    });

   // Rest of my code

    return call.sid;
  }
```

TwilioController.ts

```js
@Controller('twilio')
export class TwilioController {
  @Post('statusCallback')
  statusCallBack(@Req() request: Request): void {
    console.log(request.body.CallStatus);
  }
}
```

Log result

```bash
initiated
ringing
in-progress # at the same time as "ringing"
completed
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#get-call-status-events-during-a-call) it should not work like this.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Support Engineer here. Most likely what is happening is that the ringback tone coming from the callee side is being played after call answer. This is common when calling PBX systems or telephony systems. One way to confirm this is to call the number from your cell phone. If you see from your cell phone that the number has answered but you are hearing a ringback tone, the same will happen with your status callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I had a chance to discuss this issue with Twilio Support Team, we debugged and it looks like that my call carrier is answering the call and then redirecting it to me. Unfortunately, I don't have a chance to test my application in other ways yet, but I am almost sure that the issue is on my call carrier's side. Upvoting.